# How to create a jquery validate custom method to validate array of postcodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a custom jquery method to only allow around 500 postcodes.

I have created a custom method using Regex but it only seems to accept a few values, but not as many as I would need. I would need to insert about 500 postcodes but it would only accept around 200 in the regex.

Method ->

```
$.validator.addMethod( "postcodeUK", function( value, element ) {
  return this.optional( element ) || /^(ls1|ls2|ls3|ls4)$/i.test( value );
}, "Your postcode isnt allowed." );
```

Rule ->

```
Postcode:{
  required: true,
  postcodeUK: true
}
```

Comment: what's the requirement of valid and invalid postcode?

Comment: I have a separate method for that

Comment: Put all the valid postcode in an array and use `indexOf()` in the validate method to determine if the value matches one of them

Comment: $.validator.addMethod("Postcode", function(value, element) {
  return postcode_array.indexOf(value) == 1;
}, "The Postcode doesn't match");

I have but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Array method `indexOf` can return many different values. You could perhaps change the `==1` test to reflect if a postcode is in the array at all, or try the `array.prototype.includes` method instead.